# Find min/max in a two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, max, min, array-map

I have an array with the following format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DateTime] => "2013-05-22 14:21:01"
            [Price] => 102.01
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [DateTime] => "2013-05-23 15:55:01"
            [Price] => 52.60
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [DateTime] => "2013-05-25 14:23:01"
            [Price] => 452.25
        )
    ... etc
)
```

I need to discover the lowest and highest value of `Price`.

`min` only returns they key. I've also tried `max(array_map("max", $data))` but that only returns `452.25`.

Will I have to use a `foreach` and do it manually?

Comment: `max(array_column($data, 'Price'))` will give you the greatest price, but you won't be able to get the associated DateTime.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I just need the actual prices. Doesn't need to be associated with anything.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here's one way to get the min and max values:

```
$min = min(array_column($array, 'Price'));
$max = max(array_column($array, 'Price'));
```

To return the nested array for the min and max:

```
$prices = array_column($array, 'Price');
$min_array = $array[array_search(min($prices), $prices)];
$max_array = $array[array_search(max($prices), $prices)];
```

You could do each in one line since that looked like what you were trying to do:

```
$min_array = $array[array_search(min($prices = array_column($array, 'Price')), $prices)];
$max_array = $array[array_search(max($prices = array_column($array, 'Price')), $prices)];
```

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()` or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php).

Using `array_map()` to get just the min and max:

```
$min = min(array_map(function($a) { return $a['Price']; }, $array));
$max = max(array_map(function($a) { return $a['Price']; }, $array));
```

There's probably a good `array_filter()` or `array_reduce()` as well.

Comment: Looks great! Now I need to figure out how to get my EC2 instance to run PHP 5.5 ;) (Or I'll just got with the implementation you linked.)

Comment: Added an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think best way (easiest way) is get all prices from your array and store in a separate arrays.

Then you extract the maximum value from the new array.

Try this:

```
$myarray = array ( array( "DateTime" => "2013-05-22 14:21:01", "Price" => 102.01),
                   array( "DateTime" => "2013-05-23 15:55:01", "Price" => 52.60),
                   array( "DateTime" => "2013-05-25 14:23:01", "Price" => 452.25)
                 );

//$key is index of $myarray and $value is one of subarrays
//declare a new array to store all prices

$all_price = array();

foreach ($myarray as $key => $value)
{
    //get only "Price" from each row of array (discard "DateTime")
    $all_price[] = $value["Price"];

}

//$all_price cointains now all prices and you can get min and max

$min = min($all_price);
$max = max($all_price);

echo("Min: ".$min."<br />");
echo("Max: ".$max."<br />");
```

Copy and paste this code into http://www.writephponline.com/
to see the result! :D

Works also on PHP lower than 5.5.0

Comment: I edited my answer because I had misread the question. This solution has been tested and is very simple. You can try it in PHP tester. The link I left.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$a[]=array('name'=>'kokopiko','price'=>34);
$a[]=array('name'=>'kokospiko2','price'=>234);
$a[]=array('name'=>'kokospiko3','price'=>4);

$minmax = array_reduce($a, function($result, $item) {

    if (!isset($result['min'])) {
        $result['min']=$item;
    }
    if ($result['min']['price'] > $item['price']) {
        $result['min']=$item;
    }

    if (!isset($result['max'])) {
        $result['max']=$item;
    }
    if ($result['max']['price'] < $item['price']) {
        $result['max']=$item;
    }
    return $result; 
}); 

var_dump($minmax);
```

shorter version

```
$a[]=array('name'=>'kokopiko','price'=>34);
$a[]=array('name'=>'kokospiko2','price'=>234);
$a[]=array('name'=>'kokospiko3','price'=>4);

$init=array('min'=>$a[0],'max'=>$a[0]);

$minmax = array_reduce($a, function($result, $item) {
    ($result['min']['price'] < $item['price'])?:$result['min']=$item;
    ($result['max']['price'] > $item['price'])?:$result['max']=$item;
    return $result; 
}, $init);
```

Only min/max values ( not associated array elements

```
$min= array_reduce($a, function($result, $item) {return min($result, $item['price']);}, $a[0]['price']);
$max= array_reduce($a, function($result, $item) {return max($result, $item['price']);}, $a[0]['price']);
```