# Find row in 2d array with specific value in a column and smallest value in another column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, min

I have the following 2D array and I would like to get the key of the smallest value in the `[0]` column if `done` is equal to `no`.

```
$graph= array(
"CityA" => array(
    "0" => "1",
    "1" => "CityC",
    "done" => "no",
    ),
"CityB" => array(
    "0" => "4",
    "1" => "CityA",
    "done" => "no",
    ),
"CityC" => array(
    "0" => "5",
    "1" => "CityA",
    "done" => "no",
    ),
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find min/max in a two dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372241/find-min-max-in-a-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: Nah, I need the keys and I have a condition ^^

Comment: Have you attempted any code? SO is not a free coding service. You should show your attempts, or at least what you have searched/tried to address your issue. Have you even attempted using `min()` or `array_keys()`?

Comment: I tried a foreach loop, and some stuff with array_keys but I can't getit right

Comment: You should show what you tried with your `foreach loop, and some stuff with array_keys`. You could even show what your desired result would look like, based off your given criteria and sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
$arr = array_map(function($v){return $v[0];}, $graph);
$key = array_keys($arr, min($arr));
```

Comment: It is possible to array dereference the result of a function like this: $key = array_keys($arr, min($arr))[0]; What you think?

Comment: @arbogastes  yeah, you're right. It return an array of key or keys than have the minist value.

Comment: @KrisRoofe I edited the question, I'd be glad if you could help ! :)

Comment: you can use array_filter to filter the element have done to no. then use my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
$tes = min( array_column( $graph, 0 ) );
$key = array_search( $tes, array_column( $graph, 0 ) );
$array_keys = array_keys($graph);

echo $array_keys[$key];
```

Comment: It doesn't work, what I want here is to have `CityA` in result.
Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should perform all of your checks in a single pass through your array.

My snippet will provide the first qualifying (contains the lowest `[0]` value AND has a `done` value of `no`) row's key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X4REl))

```
$graph = [
    "CityB" => ["0" => "1", "1" => "CityA", "done" => "no"],
    "CityA" => ["0" => "1", "1" => "CityC", "done" => "no"],
    "CityD" => ["0" => "1", "1" => "CityD", "done" => "yes"],
    "CityC" => ["0" => "5", "1" => "CityA", "done" => "no"]
];

$result = [];
foreach ($graph as $key => $row) {
    if ($row['done'] === 'no' && (!isset($result[$key]) || $row[0] < $result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = $row[0];
    }
}

echo key($result) ?? 'No "done => no" rows';
```

Output:

```
CityB
```