# Cannot find min value in array to specific index

Tags: php

I have an array that have this structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "434073",
        "first_name": "Lucio Emanuel",
        "last_name": "Chiappero",
        "age": "24"
    },
    {
        "id": "330125",
        "first_name": "Luis Ezequiel",
        "last_name": "Unsain",
        "age": "23"
    }
```

my goal is search the player which have the minimum age, that in this case is 23, so `Luis Ezequiel`.

So I tried this code:

```
$index = array_search(min($players["age"]), $players);
```

the problem's that `$index` will return `false`, and this is really weird, because the `array_search` should find the index of the player which have `min` at the `age` key.

Comment: Seems like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372241/find-min-max-in-a-two-dimensional-array

Comment: @MichalCygankiewicz if I do: `$index = min(array_column($players), 'age'); ` I get null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the array into a simple array using `array_column()`. Use `min()` and `array_search()` to get the index.

```
$players = //Your array

$playersAge = array_column( $players, 'age' );             
$result = array_search(min($playersAge), $playersAge);
```

This will result to `1`

Doc: [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [min()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php), [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: whole detail an be found like `$players[$result]`